# How to fix the android studio layout preview in nexus7?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am really fresher in fragment,this is the first time I try it.Here is what I met,I dont know how to fix that,please help me.This is my `left_fragment.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `right_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="This is right fragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

They looks in the preview is,Left:
[image]

right:

[image]

And this is the `LeftFragment.class`:

```
public class LeftFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the `RightFrament.class`:

```
public class RightFrament extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the layout file `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:name="com.example.gaby.fragmenttest.LeftFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/right_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.gaby.fragmenttest.RightFrament"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this layout file's preview is like this:
[image]

I find it odd,I open it in Genymotion nexus7,It seems right.that means the android studio layout preview went wrong,How to solve that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `activity_main.xml` use the `tools:layout="..."` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
        ....
        tools:layout="@layout/left_fragment"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/right_fragment"
        ...
        tools:layout="@layout/right_fragment"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With no deletion,I add that. It prompts:'.' is not a valid resouce name character

Comment: oh yeah! I delete `.xml` suffix, It works! But why ?

Comment: @郭佳乐 You are right. Updated the answer. You have to refer the resource not the file.

Comment: Does that mean I must add `tools:layout="@layout/right_fragment" `when I use `<fragment.../>` to let the layout preview work?

Comment: Yes, it's an Android tool described here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes